# Mark a point on a sphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I am wondering if possible to mark known points (different colors or like this) on a sphere and getting its coordinates in image plane? I need that for an idea to model a fisheye camera. Any suggestions?

Comment: I try to do a circle of small sphere. May it will be going!

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question correctly but I added one possible answer to highlight points on a sphere and get their coordinates in the rendered image.

Answer (score 1):

You could give one or more faces of a sphere a different material (to make the faces smaller subdivide the sphere). Then you could render the scene and press the left mouse button make the coordinates show up.

1. First add a sphere and two materials with different colors. Then switch to edit mode and change the selection mode to faces.

[image: Create two materials and change selection mode to faces]

2. Now select one or more faces and the second (in this case red) material. Press `Assign` to assing this material to the selected face. To see the selected material in the 3D view select the shading mode `Material`.

[image: Assign the material and select "material" shading]

3. Render the scene and press the left mouse button on one of the colored points. The (image) coordinates are shown at the bottom left corner of the image view.

[image: Render and press LMB to show coordinates]

Here is an animation of the whole process.

[image: the whole process]